# How to solve a recurrence relation with generating functions?

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, relations, generating-functions

I don't really understand how to solve (with generating functions) for the recurrence relation of $$a_n = a_{n-1}+2(n-1)$$ with initial conditions of  $a_1 = 2$ when $n \geq 2$

This is what I was thinking,
\begin{align*}
    g(x) &= a_0x^0+a_1x^1+a_2x^2+...+a_rx^r+...\\
    g(x) &= a_0 + a_1x^1 + \sum^{\infty}_{n=2}a_nx^n\\
    g(x) &= 1 + 2x + \sum^{\infty}_{n=2}{(a_{n-1}+2(n-1))x^n}\\
    g(x) &= 1 + 2x + \sum^{\infty}_{n=2}a_{n-1}x^n + \sum^{\infty}_{n=2}(2n-2)x^n\\
    g(x) &= 1 + 2x + x\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \sum^{\infty}_{n=2}2n x^n - \sum^{\infty}_{n=2}2x^n\\
    g(x) &= 1 + 2x + x\sum^{\infty}_{m=1}a_{m}x^{m} + \sum^{\infty}_{n=2}2 \binom{n}{1}x^n - \sum^{\infty}_{n=2}2x^n\\
    g(x) &= 1 + 2x + x(g(x) - a_0) + \sum^{\infty}_{n=2}2 \binom{n}{1}x^n - \sum^{\infty}_{n=2}2x^n\\
\end{align*}

Comment: A *linear* recurrence relation and *two* initial conditions? That's strange, but easily fixable.

Comment: Fixed it -- thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly do not need generating functions for solving $a_n-a_{n-1}=2(n-1)$: it is enough to sum both sides on $n=1,2,\ldots,N$ to get that $a_n$ depends on $\sum_{k=1}^{n}2(k-1)$. The only issue in your case is that the given values of $a_0$ and $a_1$ do not agree with the given recurrence relation. So, let us assume $a_0=\color{red}{2}$ and $a_{n}=a_{n-1}+2(n-1)$ for any $n\geq 1$. By denoting as $f(x)$ the following generating function
$$ f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0} a_n x^n = 2+\sum_{n\geq 1}a_n x^n$$
we have
$$ x\cdot f(x) = \sum_{n\geq 0} a_n x^{n+1} = \sum_{n\geq 1} a_{n-1} x^n $$
hence by the recurrence relation
$$ (1-x) f(x) = 2+2\sum_{n\geq 1}(n-1)x^n = 2+\frac{2x^2}{(1-x)^2}$$
where the last identity follows from [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) in the form
$$ \frac{1}{(1-x)^{m+1}}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{n+m}{m}x^n.$$
 Since we have
$$ f(x) = \frac{2}{1-x}+\frac{2x^2}{(1-x)^3} $$
stars and bars also gives
$$ a_n = [x^n]f(x) = 2-n+n^2. $$

Comment: I was solving the question to "Find and solve the recurrence relation for the number of regions created by n mutually intersecting circles on a piece of paper (no three circles have a common intersection point)." so I incorrectly "set" the initial values. sorry! Do you have any recommendations for what the initial conditions should be?

Comment: @MathNewbie: you may just start with $a_1=2$, the linear recurrence relation and the generating function defined as a sum over $n\geq 1$.

Comment: makes sense - thank you.

Comment: $a_1=2$ makes sense: a circle (simple closed curve) divides the plane into two connected components (Jordan's theorem). What is debatable is to assign a value to $a_0$.

Comment: Sorry, understand that now. Thanks for the clarification